# Why are circular polarized 3D glasses for cinemas so cheap and working for a range of wavelengths?

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization, vision

Does anyone know how the filters in circular polarized 3D glasses for cinemas work (meaning how the filter on a micro-scale works, which material they use...)? Because in the lab we use of course combinations of linear polarization filters and quater-waveplates to produce circular polarization, which are 1) much more expensive than a cinema glass, and 2) provide (true) circular polarization only for one specific wavelength.

How do they make it so much cheaper for commercial glasses and how do they achieve circular polarization over the full Visible range and not for one color only?

Comment: I was under impression that linear polarization is used in cinema. But circular makes more sense.

Comment: @fraxinus I think IMAX is using linear (maybe also already moved to circular, but did it in the beginning), the others are using circular. The point is you can tilt your head and it still works using circular.